# GitLens: unable to fetch branch on visual studio code

Tags: git, gitlens

Recently I've been trying to fetch the recent changes on my work branches using the GitLens extension

However, when trying it returns the follow message, but no further details are given.

```
Unable to fetch branch 'master' from origin
```

When checking the logs it only shows the following info

- Can it be a command error from the extension itself?

```
[2023-10-30 21:38:37.473] Git.fetch
```

```
Error: Unable to fetch branch 'master' from origin
```

If I execute the `git fetch` command, it works as expected

- Other actions like pull or merge are working fine with the extension.

Can this issue be related to credentials issue? And if so, how can I add those to avoid this issue in the future?